# AngularJS: do not load view until first query return success (not 401 response)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angular-http-interceptors

In my app (generated with yeoman) i have such structure:

view:

`index.html` with `ng-view` for rendering controller view

controller:

every controller try to get some data with api urlm like:

```
$scope.getArticles = function() {
  $http.get(settings.apiBaseUri + '/app/articles/', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'If-Modified-Since': ''
      }
    })
    .success(function(response) {
      /* do some magic here :) */
    });
};

$scope.getArticles();
```

and so in every controller (+ many other queries)

and now i'm a little bit confused: **how to do not render anything, until my first request get 200 but not 401?**

here is my interceptor:

```
var deleteAuth = function(){
  $location.path('/signin');
  delete $localStorage.authStatus;
};

var responseError = function(rejection) {
  ...
  if (rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403) {
    authStatus = $localStorage.authStatus;
    if (authStatus && authStatus.isAuth && authStatus.authToken && !ipCookie('authToken') && !renewTokenAttempt) {
      deleteAuth();
    }
  }
  ...
  return $q.reject(rejection);
};
```

and all works almost 'as must be', but...

every time, i get my index.html loaded (with sidebar, logo etc) and only then i try to get (for example) my articles, and then, if i get 401 i'm redirected to `auth-page` and this is not so good: becouse i see small blink with all styles, and only then login page.

Is it real, to check first, if i get 200, and only then render page with sidebar etc, and if not: then auth-page.

How to do that?

i saw some solutions in web, but all they are huge, i need something really fast and simple)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess you try to build an SPA and you have routes in your app. You can use `resolve` before you render something. Take a look here http://www.johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/

You will have something like this:

```
'use strict';

var yeomanTestApp = angular.module('yeomanTestApp', [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
           controller: 'MainCtrl',
           resolve : {
               // add your code here to see it the user has rights or not
           }
       })
       .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
       });
    }]);
```

> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.
>
> The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:
>
> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
>   factory - {string|function}:
>   If string, then it is an alias for a service.
>   Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.

Comment: for example i visit page in new tab: still see design at first

Comment: also: in interceptor i could try to refresh token - only if unSuccessful - then redirect

Comment: what if you add an ng-if on your content?

Comment: maybe... just give some ideas, what to put in ng-if logic, thank you...
now i put something like: if 401 then hide... but maybe there are some better ideas?